# Unable to perform complete DFS on a adjacency matrix in Python

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

The nodes of graph are from 0 to 4 i.e 5 nodes labelled as A,B,C,D,E
I need to perform DFS on it starting from A , but I am unable to reach E node.

Also I need to print status of visited and unvisited nodes at every step.

```
def dfs(node, vis, un_vis, adj,mapping):
  print("visited -> ",vis)
  print("unvisited -> ",un_vis)
  print()
  vis.append(mapping[node])
  un_vis.remove(mapping[node])
  for neigh in range(0,len(adj[0])):
    if(adj[node][neigh] == 1 and mapping[neigh] in un_vis):
      dfs(neigh,vis,un_vis,adj,mapping)


adj = [[0,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,1,1],
       [1,0,0,1,0],
       [1,1,1,1,1],
       [0,1,0,1,0]]
vis = []
un_vis = ['A','B','C','D','E']
starting_node = 0
mapping = {0:'A',1:'B',2:'C',3:'D',4:'E'}
dfs(starting_node,vis,un_vis,adj,mapping)
```

I am unable to get why I am not reaching E node.

Comment: your code looks fine to me... add something like `print('visiting', mapping[node])` to the top of the function to see it's working

Answer (score 1):

You are actually reaching node E. If you have come to a conclusion looking at the print messages, this has happened because you have given the print statements before the updation of the vis and un_vis lists.

try giving the print statements after the updation and you will be able to see all the nodes in vis list. You can also print the node and neigh to see how the flow has happened and you will see that condition for node E is triggered.

```
def dfs(node, vis, un_vis, adj,mapping):
  vis.append(mapping[node])
  un_vis.remove(mapping[node])
  print("visited -> ",vis)
  print("unvisited -> ",un_vis)
  print()
  for neigh in range(0,len(adj[0])):
    if(adj[node][neigh] == 1 and mapping[neigh] in un_vis):
        print(node, neigh)
        dfs(neigh,vis,un_vis,adj,mapping)
```

Comment: Yes Got it now! Thankyou